# Colocar una palabra específica en varias celdas en excel con python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Necesito colocar la misma palabra en múltiples celdas de una misma columna. Uso el siguiente código pero me tocaría colocar la palabra n veces de acuerdo a las celdas que quiero llenar.

```
excel_wb = load_workbook('name.xlsx')
prueba_hoja = excel_wb.active
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Segmento': ["Admon", "Admon", "Admon", "Admon", "Admon",]})
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    cell = 'M%d'  % (index + 2)
    prueba_hoja[cell] = row[0]
excel_wb.save('name.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas iterando tu lista de palabras en el segmento, siendo la misma palabra podrías crear tu lista con un for utilizando un generador (opcional).

```
excel_wb = load_workbook('name.xlsx')
prueba_hoja = excel_wb.active
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Segmento': ["Admin" for x in range(5)]})
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    cell = 'M%d'  % (index + 2)
    prueba_hoja[cell] = row[0]
excel_wb.save('name.xlsx')
```

En otro caso un poco mas facil de entender sería crear una lista vacía y un for para llenar tu lista con los datos y del tamaño que necesites.

```
excel_wb = load_workbook('name.xlsx')
prueba_hoja = excel_wb.active
my_list = []
for x in range(5):
    my_list.append("Admon")
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Segmento': my_list})
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    cell = 'M%d'  % (index + 2)
    prueba_hoja[cell] = row[0]
excel_wb.save('name.xlsx')
```

Espero sea útil.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. El primer código funcionó perfecto. El segundo me salió error "TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object"...Seguiré haciendo preguntas ya que estoy automatizando un informe que debo presentar cada 15 días y me estoy demorando más de una semana para hacerlo.

Comment: Es probable que estes inicializando el objecto my_list de manera incorrecta.